# Debian is unable to find correct audio codec

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, audio, firmware

I installed Debian Testing on a new laptop ([Dell Vostro 3400](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-laptops-and-notebooks/vostro-3400-laptop/spd/vostro-14-3400-laptop)), and found the audio does not work. It seems that the only available codec is “HDMI” and the codec “Cirrus Logic CS8409” (shown in BIOS) is not detected.

**Symptoms:**

- There is no sound at all.
- The volume is not adjustable, and cannot be muted or unmuted.
- In Gnome control center, the option “Output Device” and “Input Device” is empty.

**The installed firmware packages are:**

- firmware-iwlwifi
- firmware-linux-free
- firmware-misc-nonfree
- firmware-realtek
- firmware-sof-signed

**The installed packages related to audio are:**

- alsa-topology-conf
- alsa-ucm-conf
- alsa-utils
- pipewire-audio-client-libraries
- pipewire-bin
- pipewire-pulse
- pipewire
- wireplumber

**NOTE:** The library packages (lib*) depended by the above packages are not listed here.

**Results of some Commands:**

```
$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux vostro 5.15.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.15.15-2 (2022-01-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ inxi -A
Audio:
    Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio Driver: snd_hda_intel
    Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-3-amd64 Running: yes
    Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.45  Running: yes
```

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 13: HDMI 7 [HDMI 7]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 14: HDMI 8 [HDMI 8]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 15: HDMI 9 [HDMI 9]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 16: HDMI 10 [HDMI 10]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 17: HDMI 11 [HDMI 11]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep "Codec"
Codec: Intel Tigerlake HDMI
```

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [PCH]:
    HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
    HDA Intel PCH at 0x6001138000 irq 148
```

```
$ cat /proc/asound/hwdep
00-02: HDA Codec 2
```

```
$ cat /proc/asound/modules
0 snd_hda_intel
```

```
$ cat /proc/asound/pcm
00-03: HDMI 0 : HDMI 0 : playback 1
00-07: HDMI 1 : HDMI 1 : playback 1
00-08: HDMI 2 : HDMI 2 : playback 1
00-09: HDMI 3 : HDMI 3 : playback 1
00-10: HDMI 4 : HDMI 4 : playback 1
00-11: HDMI 5 : HDMI 5 : playback 1
00-12: HDMI 6 : HDMI 6 : playback 1
00-13: HDMI 7 : HDMI 7 : playback 1
00-14: HDMI 8 : HDMI 8 : playback 1
00-15: HDMI 9 : HDMI 9 : playback 1
00-16: HDMI 10 : HDMI 10 : playback 1
00-17: HDMI 11 : HDMI 11 : playback 1
```

```
$ cat /proc/asound/timers
G0: system timer : 4000.000us (10000000 ticks)
G3: HR timer : 0.001us (1000000000 ticks)
    Client sequencer queue 1 : stopped
P0-3-0: PCM playback 0-3-0 : SLAVE
P0-7-0: PCM playback 0-7-0 : SLAVE
P0-8-0: PCM playback 0-8-0 : SLAVE
P0-9-0: PCM playback 0-9-0 : SLAVE
P0-10-0: PCM playback 0-10-0 : SLAVE
P0-11-0: PCM playback 0-11-0 : SLAVE
P0-12-0: PCM playback 0-12-0 : SLAVE
P0-13-0: PCM playback 0-13-0 : SLAVE
P0-14-0: PCM playback 0-14-0 : SLAVE
P0-15-0: PCM playback 0-15-0 : SLAVE
P0-16-0: PCM playback 0-16-0 : SLAVE
P0-17-0: PCM playback 0-17-0 : SLAVE
```

```
$ cat /proc/asound/version
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k5.15.0-3-amd64.
```

```
$ dmesg -l err
[0.875463] ima: Can not allocate sha384 (reason: -2)
```

```
$ dmesg -l warn
[0.077506] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
[0.338315] pnp 00:05: disabling [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] because it overlaps 0000:00:02.0 BAR 9 [mem 0x00000000-0xdfffffff 64bit pref]
[0.356406] hpet_acpi_add: no address or irqs in _CRS
[0.989210] acpi PNP0C14:01: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
[0.989368] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:02: WQBC data block query control method not found
[0.989370] acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
[1.022915] acpi PNP0C14:03: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
[1.029315] usb: port power management may be unreliable
[1.031770] acpi PNP0C14:04: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
[1.032117] acpi PNP0C14:05: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
[1.033757] acpi PNP0C14:06: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
[1.473885] device-mapper: core: CONFIG_IMA_DISABLE_HTABLE is disabled. Duplicate IMA measurements will not be recorded in the IMA log.
[2.475514] resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0xfedc0000-0xfedcdfff], which spans more than pnp 00:05 [mem 0xfedc0000-0xfedc7fff]
[2.475518] caller tgl_uncore_imc_freerunning_init_box+0xb7/0xf0 [intel_uncore] mapping multiple BARs
[2.485662] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[2.883776] thermal thermal_zone4: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
```

```
$ dmesg | grep "snd"
[2.488594] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[2.488846] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
```

```
$ cat /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Debian"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.unlock"
```

**Other Information:**

- There is no modprobe configuration, and the audio is enabled in BIOS.
- There is no hardware problem according to the test in BIOS.
- Command “alsamixer” shows that the card is “HDA Intel PCH” and the chip is “Intel Tigerlake HDMI”, but in BIOS, the chip is labelled “Cirrus Logic CS8409”.
- Command “wpctl” (similar to command “pactl”) shows that there is no sink.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: (1) Do `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*`. You'll see the HDMI codec, and probably also your Cirrus codec, with vendor and subsystem id etc., but without nodes. (2) Google vendor and subsystem id, and see if someone had the same problem. (3) Get the most recent kernel (download source, if necessary), have a look at the cirrus codec files in `linux/sound/pci/hda/` and see if you can add vendor/subsystem id in there, or if it already has been added, possibly with a working quirk/patch.